# Declined flag on spam - when author doesn't disclose affiliation

Tags: discussion, spam

I came across a user whose profile lists that he wrote a package. It seems that a long time ago he was only active answering questions about that package or suggesting that package as a solution to some problems, but he didn't mention his affiliation. Now he's become very active answering many questions (and giving good answers). So I don't think he's actively spamming.

Nevertheless, I thought that not disclosing affiliation constituted spam, particularly when suggesting some package that wasn't in the original question. I flagged it. I didn't see an option to explain why I thought it was spam, so it may not have been obvious to the moderator that the answerer wrote the package. My flag was declined. As I read more on it, it seems this should be spam: from [how to not be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

So for future reference,

- if I see a question that says "how do I do X?"
- and the answer is "package Y does that"
- the answerer is the author of package Y
- the answerer discloses this in his profile but not in the answer
- the answer is correct

Should I flag it?

(I am intentionally not linking to the question.)

Comment: *I don't think he's  actively spamming* is the signal to not use a spam flag.

Comment: I wouldn't have flagged it except that I had seen in discussions here that you're expected to disclose affiliations, and when I checked the information provided in the link for flagging as spam, it says right away "you *must* disclose... in your answers" (emphasis in original).  So when it was declined, figured come here and get clarity.

Comment: Sure, good thing to come to meta. The answer from Brad basically nails it. If you have doubts about raising a spam flag feel free to drop into the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room for a second opinion.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You flagged two posts as spam by a 4k user who had left nearly 200 answers. These posts suggested the use of an open source library that this user was the author of. They state that they are the author of this open source library in their profile.

The two answers did appear to be genuine attempts at helping someone, and not obvious self-promotion for their library.

It would have been nice for them to indicate in the posts themselves that this was their library, but before jumping right to a spam flag I'd suggest leaving a polite comment pointing that out. If someone has been a longtime positive contributor to the site and mentions an open source library of theirs in a couple of posts, I'd give them the benefit of the doubt. They probably thought that the disclosure of this library in their profile was enough.

Spam flags can have severe consequences for users, so we tend to be conservative about when to accept those. Again, rather than destroying these posts because they happened to mention a library of theirs, the better outcome would be to have them edit in proper disclosure and preserve the answers.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize there wold be "severe consequences".  Those clearly aren't merited here.

Comment: @Joel indeed. The UI is to blame here - your actions were entirely reasonable given the current description of the spam flag in the flagging dialog, but wildly unreasonable given a broader understanding of the effects of spam flags and when we're expected to use them - an understanding that you, through no great fault of your own, did not have.

Comment: Agreed with the answer. This is an example [how I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860533/copy-a-stream-to-avoid-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed-java-8/32619261#comment53095211_32619261) in similar situation. Since then the answerer always says that he is the author when referring his library and everybody is happy.

Answer (score 15):

Regular spam flags are for, you know, regular spam. If you see a rambling post with links to suspicious viagra suppliers use a spam flag.

In cases of self promotion without disclosure use a custom moderator attention flag and explain the situation.

Comment: The spam flag is "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation." which to mean means that just because it is an answer doesn't also mean it isn't spam.

Comment: @JoeW true, but if the post isn't _clearly_ spam, there's a good chance that your flag will be declined.  A custom mod flag lets you describe exactly what you think the issue is, when the issue may not be so obvious.

Comment: What if the links to the viagra suppliers aren't at all suspicious? Maybe we need a Viagra Overflow for such legitimate posts?

Comment: @JoeW I think `only` is the important word in that quote. The answer also solves someone's problem, so strictly speaking the quote says it should not be flagged as spam. I would therefore disagree that it can be spam and an answer at the same time.