# How would you proceed with this edit review?

Tags: discussion, edits

I was checking the suggested edit queue, when I got to [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11049139). The edited answer is basically a link to a tool that is no longer available, and the edit is just striking through the link and adding a comment stating that the tool is not available anymore.

So now my doubt(s):

- I think I should reject the edit because it doesn't improve the answer (a comment would fit better), but I don't feel like any of the rejection options fit the case:

  - It's not spam or vandalism.
  - The changes do not affect readability
  - Doesn't really conflict with the author's intent (it's just a comment about the tool availability).
  - It's not an attempt to reply.
- I feel like the answer in itself should be flagged/deleted as it is no longer a valid answer, but again I don't feel like any of the flagging options fit the case:

  - It's not spam (or it could be as the author doesn't state that is/was the developer)
  - It is not rude or offensive.
  - It is an answer (or at least it used to be).
  - It is not something to bug the moderators about.

How would you proceed in that case?

(Probably by the time that I get the answer, someone will have approved/rejected the edit, but at least I'll learn something).

Comment: Downvote and flag as low quality, the current comment on the post should help with deletion. The edit should be rejected and placed as a comment instead, because as you said, it doesn't improve the answer at all (However, after seeing the rejection-comment, I am inclined to believe it *does* make the answer more accurate, though within its own scope...).

Comment: @CubeJockey I will swear a thousand times that the "very low quality" option was not there 10 minutes ago when I clicked on the flag link

Comment: The question it answers is a tool request. Probably on-topic when it was asked (2008), but off-topic nowadays. Voted to close it.

Comment: And about the edit: "No improvement whatsoever" then?

Comment: It's not "Very Low Quality". It's a link-only answer, which makes it "Not an Answer".

Comment: @S.L.Barth within the scope of the question (a tool request), it is an answer. Though since the answer now points to a 404'd page, I'd wager that makes the answer low-quality.

Comment: @CubeJockey Low Quality, yes. Very Low Quality, no. Although with the tool now unavailable, the answer might as well be deleted.

Comment: An answer pointing to a non-existent tool isn't very low quality? It certainly does have "severe [...] content problems" and "need[s] to be removed." Eventual low quality flag pedantry aside, yes, it should be deleted.

Comment: Nuke the question. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Reject as attempt to reply, because that's what it is, then flag as not an answer, because it isn't an answer.

Comment: it has been made painfully clear that link only answers **are answers** in that **answer** is extremely loosely defined now as **any attempt at providing some kind of answer to the question no matter how poor qualifies as an answer**; *This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.* as such *link only answers qualify as answers* as they are **attempting** to answer the question. Flagging them all as **Not an Answer** will just reward you with a flag ban very quickly.

Comment: and link only answers flagged as *Very Low Quality* will generally earn you **declined** just because they are wasting moderators time and they do not qualify anymore as the description is now; *This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.* Link only answers **are salvageable through editing**. Anyone can edit or submit an edit and include relevant information from the link. So inevitable flag ban again is in your future if you flag all link only answer as *VLQ*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Link-only answers are a bit of an edge case. I agree they are salvageable through editing and hence not VLQ. According to the [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post on MSE, they are NAA. However, NAA flags on answers that are highly upvoted and/or accepted are often declined, or so I'm told.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson no, true link only answers are NaA, however, if you can strip the link markup and it is still an attempt to answer a question conceivably asked on Stack Overflow, then it is an answer. This answer does not fit that as per shog's apple analogy.

Comment: @S.L.Barth if the answer is upvoted or accepted then it may quite possibly be declined because mods will want you to try editing the answer first to redeem it. If that cannot be done, use a custom flag and explain how you've tried to redeem the answer, but are unable, and why you believe that community delete votes aren't sufficient to remove the answer.

Comment: My opinion is that they are NAA & VLQ. My opinion is not the same as what I posted, which is what you will be told when you get the **declined** message from the pissed off moderator(s) because for whatever reason refuse to make a judgement call that might be questioned as too aggressive in removing content.

Comment: "(or it could be as the author doesn't state that is/was the developer)" -- That does make it spam. [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): "However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers." (However, somewhat confusingly, [it doesn't necessarily mean it needs to be flagged as spam.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306540))

Comment: As the accepted answer shows: if an answer just links to a tool, and being pointed to that tool answers the question, it *is* a (low-quality) answer to the question. When that link breaks, removing the answer for that reason deprives future readers of a valid, helpful (albeit low-quality) answer to the question. Removing answers for such reasons *decreases* the quality of the site.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I see that the answer has been deleted. I think it was done a bit too fast, because by googl'ing 5min I found out that the link from the answer:

> http://www.github.com/vanyamikhailov/minifire

Is now:

> https://github.com/vanmik/Minifire

The author just changed his github name. If you look at his profile you will see that it is Vanya Mikhailov account.

Could someone undelete the answer and fixed the link? It might help someone in the future.

And, to answer the question, I would have done what I just did to see if I could fix the link. If I could, I would have reject and edit, if not reject as attempt to reply - IMO this should be a comment, notifying the answerer that his link is not valid anymore.

Comment: Good point, and thanks. I tried to find the user but just checked http://www.github.com/vanyamikhailov/, maybe I should have searched further

Answer (score 26):

When in doubt, Skip.

I'd be inclined to reject it as "attempt to reply" - it replies to the answerer that the link is now dead. It's probably better to put this information in a comment, rather than outright editing the answer.

But Approve would not be entirely wrong in this case.
Verify that the tool is indeed gone, and that the answer wasn't spam. (If it was spam, it shouldn't be edited - it should be flagged).
If both conditions are met, then the edit is technically correct.
Also, it does not remove information. It's not removing the link, which might be useful if someone knows the way to a backup of the project.

Comment: I agree, I think the edit *does* improve the answer.  Not clicking a broken link is better than clicking a broken link.

Answer (score 1):

If an edit would have been a better fit as a comment, then it **is** an attempt to reply. (What else would you call a comment?)

Thus the most appropriate action is to reject the edit as an attempt to reply.

As for the answer, if you feel strongly that it's incorrect or otherwise of low value, but not deserving of moderator attention (i.e. not worth flagging), then downvote it, like you would any other incorrect or low-value answer. If you don't feel strongly enough about it to downvote it, then leave it alone.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this is a bad edit; and as such I would decline it without hesitation.

At the time the question was asked -and the answer was written-, it was a perfectly valid answer. That would mean that this edit invalidates the answer to the question, as it basically removes the answer by saying it's obsolete.

To me, this feels like going to a question asking about Java 3, only to change a valid Java 3 answer, saying Java 3 is now obsolete. Yes, it's true, but that was not the question!

Don't attempt to change history, but add to it.
This edit would have been perfect if it had been a comment.

Comment: 1. You don't have enough rep to review suggested edits yet 2. This answer was a non answer when it was posted. For it to be an answer it would have to explain how it could solve the problem without introducing new problems. It is basically "use this thing", which isn't an answer

Comment: Editing a non-answer to a non-answer-that-is-not-valid-anymore is just as bad. Leave it as it is; post a comment.

Comment: I agree with rejecting the edit, but not your reasoning.