# Dead links: is vandalizing the post acceptable?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, broken-link

I spotted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451238/451238) in the edit queue. [The edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11063157), TBH, makes me cringe. It's unsightly at best and the next reviewer clearly thought he was doing some good by keeping the strike-through and adding Wayback Machine links.

Is this really a good way to deal with this?

Comment: That is not a good way of going about it, especially since it introduced invalid HTML (`<strike>...</a></strike>`). Not to mention the all-caps-in-bold monstrosity of text. Just a parentheses around a short note, *(link dead, see archive.org)* would be more than sufficient.

Comment: My eyes.  Those bold caps are harmful to my eyes.

Comment: I went through and edited it back to what it was but with the web archive links.

Comment: The main thing I take umbrage with is that the post is so heavily dependent on those links.  If *that's* the case, perhaps the answer should be deleted?

Comment: @Makoto - Is the question even on topic anymore? At one point the OP actually says that they'd prefer a non-programming solution. Several of the answers there are link only answers.

Comment: The intention is honorable, the execution is a bit, cough.  Why do you care about this old crap?  If you do then just fix the edit.

Comment: Seems like this user [has been doing a lot of this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315588/how-would-you-proceed-with-this-edit-review).

Comment: @MikeC It looks like this specific user is actively looking for dead links and doing the same thing.  I looked through his more recent dozen or so suggested edits and most are doing the same exact thing.

Comment: _"is vandalizing the post acceptable?"_ -- I'm reminded of a certain politician who, when asked "is discriminating based on religion is acceptable?", answered "I don't know, you tell me." If the word "vandalized" is in fact the best word to describe what happened, surely you don't need to ask the question. In that case, it seems more like a thinly veiled "call to arms" for The Meta Mob. If that's not the best word, then it seems like the question has been formulated in an intentionally prejudicial way.

Comment: I've flagged this user for mods - this form of editing is a waste of time, and there are better ways to deal with these answers (which aren't made better by striking out the link)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think that the proposed edit is a good way to deal with dead links. In this special case, the strike-through tags introduced invalid HTML, as mentioned by @MikeMcCaughan. In general, strike-through text introduces a revision history within the post. This shouldn't be, because we have the revision history for that. A post should always contain the latest version only.

And I think that the **ALL-CAPS-IN-BOLD** text is not really an option already became clear from the comments, too. Nobody gets harmed when somebody clicks on a (truly) dead link.

Regarding the dead links: If I discover a dead link, then I usually try to replace it by a valid one. If I can't find a replacement link using Google, then I usually ask the OP whether they can update the link in their post.
However, replacing dead links by Wayback Machine links also seems legit to me. IMHO, marking a link as dead doesn't add any value.

Of course, things are different for links that are not dead, but lead to malware instead. If such links cannot be updated, then I think they should be removed and the edit summary should reflect that the original link now leads to malware.

Comment: "Nobody gets harmed when somebody clicks on a dead link." Unless the "dead link" isn't one that leads nowhere, but one that leads to malware (hey, I rhymed).

Comment: Right, and if everything we did was predicated only on whether anyone was harmed or not, then, well, we probably wouldn't do very much. It's the internet. Most of time we just want to make life _better_; saving people need not be part of that, and often isn't.

Comment: I was just addressing the all-caps-in-bold text. It looks like a stern warning that should tell you: If you click this link, then bad things will happen. This is not the case for dead links. Of course, things are different for links that lead to malware. If such links cannot be updated, then they should be removed, I think. And the edit summary should reflect that the original link now leads to malware.