# Flagging as spam an answer that promotes a GitHub project

Tags: support, flags, spam

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470460/adding-settings-class-to-a-uwp-app) today that was asked and answered by the same user, almost at the same time. In the answer, he suggests using a GitHub project for which he is the only contributor.

Nowhere in his question, answer and/or profile (which is in Spanish, my main tongue) does he mention being the author or contributor to the project.

I raised a flag asking for a moderator to check it out with the following explanation:

> This question was asked and answered by the same user, with the answer
>   pointing to a github project whose only contributor is the same user:
>   stackoverflow.com/users/583336/…
>   github.com/joseangelmt/ObservableSettings/graphs/contributors This
>   looks like an attempt to advertise his github project. I didn't mark
>   this as spam as it may not be as clear as a typical spam answer, needs
>   checking profiles

To me this is a clear attempt of advertising his project. The question and answer themselves may be good and useful for the community, but by asking and answering the question in this way, **should it be considered spam**?

I'm doubtful about how to deal with these situations, especially after reading [this SO Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306540/declined-flag-on-spam-when-author-doesnt-disclose-affiliation).

Comment: It's definitely not spam in the traditional sense, but it's not completely savoury either. I would leave it up to the community in that specific tag to determine whether it's worth keeping around

Comment: Well, if his project does not impact performance and carries no locks on the settings file, I think he may be onto something useful tbh, I'm a XAML / UWP developer myself; I even give UWP trainings to other companies :P

Comment: Project spam happens, this isn't it.  He took the answer to the question he posted yesterday and ran with it.  Very properly attributed the answerer btw.  I see nothing but good faith.  The meta effect is slamming it hard, that's sad.

Comment: Agree, @HansPassant,  It seems like he wrapped the answer from the other question in a generic usable form and basically used the Q&A format of SO to create a blog post about his library. I think his intentions are good, and in the Git page itself he gives due credit to StackOverflow, and his answer could deserve an upvote by itself. But still it's debatable if this whole thing is useful. After all, it's his question. Other people looking for this answer, if they exist at all, could as well find him on Git, or in the other question he asked, where he could somehow link to his project

Comment: @GolezTrol I chose not to downvote him just because of that, I think it can be helpful.

Comment: Going by the rapid voting, I'd say there was some dubious behaviour there too.

Comment: @BanksySan Or it got linked to on a meta thread that has been viewed 425 times in the last 7 hours. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: Maybe... it's like Hiesenburg predicted.  We can observe a question without changing it's state.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

After taking a good look at the question and the answer, three observations:

1. Both the question and the answer are well formulated, give plenty information and solve a valid problem.
2. The link is necessary. He's describing the use of a class and class names are not unique. ('The' class `FDistribution` in JAVA for example exists in 2 different packages and both versions behave vastly different.) So you want to know which exact class is referred to, a link is very useful.
3. There is not a single way the OP can get any money from that link.

Yes, the OP is using Stack Overflow to inform people about a valid solution he found for a valid problem. My check: If the OP would copy-paste all the code on github into the answer, it would be a valid - but unreadable - answer.

The OP could have mentioned he was the developer of that repo to avoid this discussion, but other than that, there's nothing wrong with that question.

Comment: OP has now added a statement that the repo is theirs.

Answer (score 48):

The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room handles a lot of spam. For most of it, it's 100% clear that there is no intent to share knowledge or add value.

Posts by users that link to their own blog or GitHub repo are always good for fierce debate, also among the seasoned spam fighters in the earlier mentioned room.

These are my personal checks when following a link:

- Do I end-up on a pay-wall?
- Do I end-up on an advertisement riddled page?
- Does the virus scanner block the site?
- Is the external site owned by the OP?
- Is the post not useful without the link?
- Is it neither a personal blog nor a code-repo?
- Multiple posts of the OP have a link to the same site?

If any of these are answered Yes, then I raise a spam flag.

The post(s) under discussion don't have a Yes on any of these checks, so I would not raise a spam flag.

If this seems to be the first case of a actual attempt to provide value I leave a comment to [How not to be spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

In the post under discussion I would choose the option to leave a comment. The post doesn't come close to being spam. Self answering is **NOT** a reason to use a spam flag, it is encouraged in the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Let there be no misunderstanding of 6 spam flags: those carry 6 down votes on the post and a -100 reputation penalty. So if it is not a serial offender I would be very careful to use that flag on users that try to add value.

If you need different (strong) opinions drop in the chat room and discuss it for the best call to action.

Comment: Commenting and explaining is always the right way. Mistakes happen. If a user posted once a low-quality answer with a link to one of his repositories then discuss with him to find a solution and add value to the answer.

Comment: I agree with commenting when the idea behind a post is to provide help to somebody's issue. But when you post the issue and solution, it is basically a blog post and/or advertisement. In any case, I was not aware of the chat option, which I will use form now on :)

Comment: Self answering is an option and even mentioned and encouraged in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I don't understand why it often receives so much negativity for the sole reason of being a self answer. @NahuelIanni

Comment: For the reason that he asked a question for which he already had the answer, which was using a tool he created an hour before posting the question itself. Also, don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to say he did somwthing wrong, I'm asking if it right to do so in such a way.

Comment: Yes, that is the strict line of reasoning you'll find with the other members of the SOCVR room. I'm more on the assume good faith path.

Comment: Imo, @rene this case is less egregious then your normal spammer. He is advertising his own library, yes, but its a) entirely free and b) not riddled with ads (its his own github page). It may be in poor taste, but flagging it as spam feels like the nuclear option on a user that might just need a nudge.

Comment: @Magisch do I say somewhere that the post needs to be flagged as spam?

Comment: @rene Not explicitly, but I got that vibe from it. If that was unintentional, my apologies.

Comment: @Magisch Hmm, OK. I edited it to make it more clear

Answer (score 24):

I'm the creator of the post. Should I delete the link to GitHub? I don't want to break Stack Overflow rules or be considered a spammer.

Comment: Do you consider the link to GitHub useful for somebody just looking for information? If so, I'd personally add a disclaimer to your answer stating that you're the developer of that code. If the link to GitHub doesn't add any extra information, I wonder why you'd put it in in the first place.

Comment: I would only make explicit that is your own github repo you link to for convenience of the users who want to try your answer. I appologize for the bad experience you have with that answer.

Comment: @rene Well, there is ample compensation for the fuss, in additional publicity and voting. If it were not a good post though...

Comment: Solved, I deleted the link because I don't want to be accused of spam. I know it for next time. The link was actually to download a complete example but I think it is well explained in SO.

Comment: @JoséÁngelMartínezTorres I'd leave the link but mentioning it is for your own repository. No harm in doing so :)

Comment: From [Stack Overflow help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): *"... if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you **must disclose your affiliation** in your answers."* No problem linking to your own project, but you should mention in the post that you're the project owner.

Comment: Done, I moved the link to the end of the answer and explained that I was who created the repository for the purpose of download a functional example. Thanks @Pang. Now I know it for the next time. I want to share a lot of knowledge, so next time, or I won't share any link or I'll disclose my affiliation. Maybe if StackOverflow had any way to upload projects, everything would be easier.

Answer (score 5):

My own view (which in the past for other things tends to be down-voted very quickly) is that it should be kept in mind that someone providing an answer is usually trying to do a favor and it should be treated as such if there is no obvious reason to do otherwise.  If the code is free, clean, and the website is too, the default is to not be spam.  Conversely, if people spam-flag attempts at such projects, they will eventually go away, and anyone who would benefit from them will not.  In the opposite situation (not spam-flagging these), there is little harm if, once again the code is free,  clean, and the website is too.  But that's just all my opinion of course.