# Spam or not, that's the question

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-answer

In the Late Answers queue I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15998078):

> Anybody interested in asynchronous updating a template using AJAX can use django-async-include (GitHub repository).
>
> This project makes it easy changing an static block inclusion to a asynchronous one. That's perfect for inclusion of computational-heavy template block.
>
> Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this project.

1. It does include a link to an offsite source, of which the poster is the author.
2. He does disclaim the above in his post.
3. It doesn't seem to be a for-profit project.
4. It might actually be a helpful answer to the post. (I'm not skilled enough to properly judge this.)

Does this qualify as spam?

Comment: The answerer could have also explained *how* to use the tool.... but otherwise they're doing everything right, so it doesn't warrant a spam flag.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That question is about a person posting and answering a question to possibly promote his project. This is a different case as this considers only an answer and the content of the post is significantly different.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**No, it doesn't.**

*Spam* is this:
[image]

Alternatively, it's consistent undisclosed self-promotion. That's the more likely case in this scenario, so now ask yourself:

- Is this user posting this tool as *every* answer they post (or a significant proportion thereof)?
- Is this user avoiding disclosing their affiliation to the tool when they post about it?

If the answer to either of those is *yes*, then it probably warrants a custom moderator flag to let the moderators know so they can look into the situation and warn the user involved. However, in this case, the answer to both is no (the user only has one answer in total, so it's not really fair to them to call it a consistent pattern).

If they continue to post about the tool without posting any other useful content that doesn't mention it, then you should look at flagging it.

Comment: Posts aren't judged by who posted them or what else that user has posted. It's either spam or it's not. In this case, it's not, but that has nothing to do with the user. This is the right conclusion for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I disagree.  There are examples like [How is this answer spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334123/how-is-this-answer-spam) that pop up as spam audits in which a single answer on its own may not have been considered spam, but when you look at the users full body of work, it was determined to be spam and the user was suspended.

Comment: To an extent, @Josh. True *spam*, like the image I've included here, is either spam or not, you're dead right there. Self-promotion is more murky, and involves the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Audits where the reviewer is expected to make a judgment based on invisible information are just emblematic of the problem, @psubsee2003. (They also constitute a problem in themselves.)

Comment: I'd like to point to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317127/flagging-as-spam-an-answer-that-promotes-a-github-project) here in meta that might be useful in this case

Answer (score 16):

It's not spam, but it's not terribly useful as an answer either, it doesn't explain how to use the offsite solution to solve the problem the question asker has.

A useful answer would say something like I've developed a library called XXX to solve this problem. Here's how you would use my library to solve this issue...

An explanation on top of that as to how to solve the issue without the library would be better still. Presumably the answerer knows how to do that since they wrote the library. That might be just an overview if the answer would be particularly complicated.

Downvoting is the recommended action for answers that are not useful. It's up to you whether you think that the answer is or isn't useful of course.

If someone adds identical generic answers to multiple questions the moderators will remove them all. If you come across a case where they have not done so you could explain the situation in a custom flag if it seems like they are using the site solely or mainly as a vehicle for self promotion. Flagging is not appropriate for a single answer or even a small number of answers amongst a greater whole.